# pynag package not showing up in apt-get?

Tags: apt, python, nagios3

I need to install `pynag`, following the readme: http://code.google.com/p/pynag/source/browse/README.md

It says to use apt-get. But it doesn't appear it found any packages?

```
sudo apt-get install python-pynag pynag
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pynag
E: Unable to locate package pynag
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

`pynag` and `python-pynag` were added to the repositories in Ubuntu 13.10, so you'll need to use another option to install them.